# circular reference using weak variables causing the unwrapping of nils

Tags: arrays, swift, reference, weak

let me start off by saying I searched to find a topic that would help me but I could not anything that helped. Here is my situation...

I created a class `sign` where I created the variable `thing1`. I then created an array called `arrayX` that uses `sign`. Then I used a NSURL session to pull values from a domain. I then created `thingX` that will hold that value and finally I appended my `arrayX` with that value of `thingX`. This works GREAT except that it appears i have strong circular references and the memory cannot be deallocated. I tried fixing it with weak references but then the occasional empty `thingX` causes my app to crash because it is trying to unwrap a nil. Please help!!!

```
class sign {

    var thing1        = ""

    init(thing1: String) {

        self.thing1   = thing1

    }

}


var arrayX : [sign] = [sign]()


index1 = 0

while index1 < count {

      //NSURL will grab info info will grab a value from my domain and thingX will be given this value (occasionally the value will be empty)

     let thingX = ‘NSURL value’  as! String

     let data1 = sign(thing1: thingX)
     self.arrayX.append(data1)

     index1++

}
```

Comment: If you have a loop that you want to run a definite amount of times, such as your while loop that you want to run 'count' times, you should consider using a for loop instead of a while loop.

Comment: count will be different based on how much data the domain has in it at any particular point in time. count will be different. My memory is just building up and up and up every time this block of code is executed.

Comment: Does this code compile?  Sure looks like `var arrayX:[sign] = sign` has no chance.

Comment: it compiles and runs GREAT until I try and make data1 a weak reference - then it crashes and says its because it unexpectedly unwrapped a nil

Comment: I don't understand what you think your circular reference is, or why making data1 a weak reference will help. You create a `sign` object inside your loop, so it has 1 reference and local scope inside the loop. You append it to the array so now it has a second reference held by the array outside of the loop. You then leave the loop, removing the reference held by the data1 variable, but the array reference still exists until the object is either removed from the array or the array is deallocated.

Comment: What leads you to believe that the issue is a circular reference, and why are you force unwrapping your NSURL? Why not have your code say `if let thingX = ‘NSURL value’  as? String {` instead

Comment: Will M. how does the array get deallocated? I thought that by the initial call   var arrayX : [sign] = [sign]()     it would do that every time that storyboard is accessed.

Comment: @JustAnotherGuy It should just be deallocated automatically when its no longer used i.e. it goes out of scope or all references to the object containing it are gone.

Comment: @JustAnotherGuy could you post more context? Where does the code outside of the class exist? What is the actual issue that you are seeing? You say "it appears i have strong circular references and the memory cannot be deallocated" but what has led you to that conclusion?

Comment: Will - so here is more information... When I look at the memory report in the debug session and I run this block of code over and over again the memory usage increases and never goes down. I am trying to understand how my code uses memory and I though because data1 has thing1 and thingX in it that it was a circular reference with the class sign